# Creating a state machine designer using WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, state-machine

I am going to attempt to write a state machine designer using WPF that will allow me to create something like [this](http://www.lassalle.com/html5/demo/index.htm).

Does anyone know how I can go about doing something like this in C#?  I want the user to be able to create individual states, name them and create transitions to other states (using curves to join the states together).

Comment: When asking a question always include **why** you are attempting something. Is there something about state machines you do not understand? Or do you want a "state machine designer"? There is a powerful one already available at http://www.jflap.org/. Why must you create another one?

Comment: If you're doing this for a real production purpose, then as others have said you'd be better off spending your time looking for a third-party solution (Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5 has a great designer, includes a State Machine and is part of the standard .NET runtime). If it's learning exercise, then get learning and stop trying to get all the answers from StackOverflow ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [Stateless Designer](http://statelessdesigner.codeplex.com/)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this with nodexl (http://nodexl.codeplex.com/).  I was able to create a fully function viewer/editor by combining nodexl with with parts of Stateless Designer (http://statelessdesigner.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Ambitious! You need a diagramming tool, like [Go Diagram](http://www.nwoods.com/components/dotnet/godiagram-overview.htm) or [MindFusion WpfDiagram](http://mindfusion.eu/wpfdiagram.html).

There may be an alternative state machine diagramming tool, but I'm personally not aware of one.

Should be interesting to see the results.

Comment: I was afraid of that kind of answer as I was hoping to write a bespoke one for myself.

Comment: Just to add - teleriks diagramming component looks promising http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/diagrams.aspx

Comment: I'd rather not have to pay for a third party tool as I cannot justify paying for one.  The whole point of writing the tool myself is that I have full control of the code.  I want the state machine designer to be able to generate full C# code to implement the state machine that is being designed.

Comment: Check out Nevron Diagram for .NET:

https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-diagram-overview.aspx

It has great support for many types of connectors and automatic layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Expression Blend provides support for state transitions.
Thus, Expression Blend is taylor-made for WPF driven UX.